# How to plot membership function of Type 3 fuzzy logic in 3D?

Tags: isosurface

I would like to plot these figures attached in 3D using isosurface.

[membership function in3D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ws4gJ.gif)
[membership function in3D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIunB.gif)

I know the built in function in matlab (isosurafce ()) but i didn't have data for V .
I can't get a relation between x,y,z and V all I know That the 3D plot of the IT3MF is an isosurface with volume in between the layers of the surface formed by all the secondary IT2MFs (gauss ) in green color in the second plot attached which forms the domain of uncertainty (DOU) of IT3 FS